# How to solve a while loop that suddenly terminates itself?

Tags: c++

I have code to look for permutations which takes input from the user until the user is satisfied with the amount of input added.

However, when receiving more than 4x input, the code suddenly stuck/terminated itself. I've tried changing the array type to dynamic memory, but the result continues to be the same.

Strangely when I test this code using http://cpp.sh/, it runs normally. I think the problem is with my compiler (I used VS code and MinGW to compile and run it.) What do you think is wrong?

My code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int KombAngka;
    bool Lanjut = true;
    int x = 0;
    int *Angka = new int(x);
    
    string YaTidak;
        
    while(Lanjut) {         
        
        cout << "Number-" << x + 1 << ": "; 
        cin >> Angka[x];
        
        LoopYaTidak:

        cout << "Are the numbers enough?(y/n)?: ";
        cin >> YaTidak;

        if (YaTidak == "y") {
            Lanjut = false;
        }
        else if (YaTidak == "n") {
            Lanjut = true;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Enter the correct answer!(y/n)" << endl;
            goto LoopYaTidak;
        }
        
        x++;
    
    }

    cout << "All numbers: (";

    for (int z = 0; z <= x - 2; z++) {
        cout << Angka[z] << ", ";
        }

    cout << Angka[x - 1] << ")" << endl;

    cout << "The number of combinations of numbers used: ";
    cin >> KombAngka;

    int JumlahAngka = x;
    const int StopLoop = JumlahAngka - KombAngka;

    for (int i = JumlahAngka - 1; i > StopLoop; i--) {
        JumlahAngka = JumlahAngka * i;
    } 
      
    cout << "The number of queue numbers consisting of " << KombAngka << " different numbers are " << JumlahAngka << endl;
    
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are using a pointer to an int as an array. This will cause buffer overflow and thus undefined behaviour. Make an array of appropriate size or use a vector.

Comment: `int *Angka = new int(x);` is not an array.

Comment: Use std::vector and push_back numbers to it, it will manage memory for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
int *Angka = new int(x);
```

creates an integer on the heap with a value held by `x` which here it is `0`.

You are accessing memory which you should not, and as mentioned by @fredrik it may cause a buffer overflow.

If you want to create an array on the heap you should do

```
int *Angka = new int[x];
```

This creates an array (on heap) of size `x`.

But since you are using c++ it's better to use vectors, you can simply create a vector with

```
std::vector<int> Angka;
```

Vector will take care of memory allocation and all other stuff that you would have to handle if you were to create an array with `new`.